# How to create Pandas data frame from a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a tuple,named a, with 10 columns.Sample data looks like

```
((12, '22', '32'),
Column-1    Column-2    Column-3    colum-4 Column-5    Colum-6 Colum-7 Week    ACCT_YEAR   NAME
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-1
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-2
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-3
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-4
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-5
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-6
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-7
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-8
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-9
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-10
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-11
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-12
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-13
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   52  2016    Name-14)
```

I want to convert it to pandas data frame. So I used following code

```
y=pd.DataFrame(list(a))
```

But y.shape[0] is showing 2 & after printing y,I'm seeing it contains 2 rows,where second row is column heading & first row contains data for some of the columns & None for other columns also it has more columns than my tuple a has. Can you please suggest me how to do it correctly in python 3.6

The output of a.**repr**() is given below

```
((12, '22', '32'),       Column-1 Column-2 Column-3        Column-4 Column-5  \\\n1101         12      22         32  ...         ...   \n1102         12      22         32  ...         ...   \n1103         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1104         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1105         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1106         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1107         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1108         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1109         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1110         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1111         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1112         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1113         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1114         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1115         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1116         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1117         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1118         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1119         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1120         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1121         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1122         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1123         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1124         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1125         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1126         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1127         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n1128         12      22         32  ...          ...   \n\n     Column-6           Column-7   W20162016k 51CC51_Y201651R   \\\n1101   ...  ...  515151P325151M51            2016   \n1102   ...       ...           51            51   \n1103   ...        ...      0000453            2016   \n1104   ...        ...      0000512            2016   \n1105   ...      ...            51            51   \n1106   ...      ...            51            51   \n1107   ...      ...            51            51   \n1108   ...       ...           51            51   \n1109   ...        ...      0000561            2016   \n1110   ...        ...      0000871            2016   \n1111   ...      ...            51            51   \n1112   ...      ...            51            51   \n1113   ...      ...            51            51   \n1114   ...       ...           C51            51   \n1115   ...        ...      0000604            51   \n1116   ...      ...            51            51   \n1117   ...      ...            51            51   \n1118   ...       ...           511            51   \n1119   ...       ...           51            51   \n1120   ...       ...           51            51   \n1121   ...       ...           51            51   \n1122   ...       ...           51            51   \n1123   ...       ...           51            51   \n1124   ...       ...           51            51   \n1125   ...       ...           51            51   \n1126   ...       ...           51            51   \n1127   ...       ...           51            51   \n1128   ...       ...           5151            51   \n\n     N51M2016  \n1101                     C  \n1102                     C  \n1103                     C  \n1104                     C  \n1105                     C  \n1106                     C  \n1107                     C  \n1108                     C  \n1109                     C  \n1110                     C  \n1111                     C  \n1112                     C  \n1113                     C  \n1114                     C  \n1115                     C  \n1116                     C  \n1117                     C  \n1118                     C  \n1119                     C  \n1120                     C  \n1121                     C  \n1122                     C  \n1123                     C  \n1124                     C  \n1125                     C  \n1126                     C  \n1127                     C  \n1128                     C  )"
```

Comment: can you please run this: `a.__repr__()` and post the results?

Comment: Hi @joaoavf, I have added the outcome in my original post

Comment: I can't replicate this tuple here as it gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` as it looks like it would throw as there are values that contain undefined variables (and should probably be strings).

Comment: @joaoavf yes, it contain string. Please create a tuple of your own data in my format & then kindly show me the steps

Comment: I am not really sure on how to do that, I thought that `__repr__()` would do the job, but it didn't, I am not really sure on what to do now to be honest.

Comment: To me it looks like you start with an inconsistent tuple. The first value of `a` seems not to be part of the data frame. Try to convert only the second part `a[1]` into a dataframe. Knowing the type of the data you try to convert will also hint towards a solution: `type(a[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer strongly depends on the String in your tuple. If what you copied is actually whats in the string, you have to convert the string to something pandas can parse, that's why I added the regex substitution.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import re
a = (('12','22','32'),
     """Column-1    Column-2    Column-3    colum-4 Column-5    Colum-6 Colum-7 Week    ACCT_YEAR   NAME
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-1
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-2
12  22  32  …   …   …   …   51  2016    Name-3""")
# The following substitution is only valid if there are absolutely no spaces in values
b = re.sub(string=a[1], pattern=' +', repl=',')
y = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(b))
y
```

NB: this answer assumes the first value in tuple `a` is not part of the data that should be read into the DataFrame. This makes it more into the question how to read data saved in a string into a pandas.DataFrame rather than a tuple.

Comment: Hi @fabianegli,The data I have given is dummy data, not the actual data. Yes,first value of tuple is not part of my data. Fourth to 10th column of my tuple,except 6th column,which contains number. I tried your code `b = re.sub(string=a[1], pattern=' +', repl=',')` & got the error message `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: What is the type of `a[1]`? You can check with `type(a[1])`

Comment: Please give me some time. I'm working something else. I will put type of a[1] by end of day

Comment: my problem resolved.`type(a[1])` is pandas data frame

Comment: Thanks for letting us know; and accepting my answer.